# Modify grub on bootable usb

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard

I have a windows laptop with a confused keyboard that keeps thinking that the windows key is being held down.  When I use the Ubuntu 20.04 bootable usb it still thinks that the windows key is being pressed. I would like to modify the usb to disable the keyboard.

One recommendation is to add "i8042.nokbd" but I am not sure where to add it to the bootable usb. Another way is to have

```
'xinput disable "keyboard name from xlist e.g. AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"'
```

but again I do not know where to add this.

Thank you.

Comment: What tool did you use to make the USB? mkusb, YUMI, Universal, Rufus and UNetbootin will allow you to modify GRUB. dd, Etcher and Gnome-Disks will not.

Comment: Rufus was used.

Comment: In Windows Files, you can open the Rufus USB on the left side of the window and then open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for editing. I an not sure where to  add "i8042.nokbd" in grub.cfg. I would try adding it at the end of the `linux` line in the first menuentry one space before ---.